# Django access ForeignKey field and get their values

Tags: python, django

I`m trying to build a small webshop platform where a user can create a shop, select a category of products and add products to it.

To achieve my goal I created this simplified models.py

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    org_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owned_by = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.company_name} ORG'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('org-view', kwargs={'pk': self.org_id})

class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = ( ('electric', 'Electronics'), ('food', 'FrozenFood'), ('shoes', 'slippers') )
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORIES)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cat_name} Category'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cat-view', kwargs={'id': self.pk})

class Product(models.Model):
    org_id = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    cat_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

In my views i want to keep the user on a single page where he can manage his shop.

My current views.py:

```
class OrganizationDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView, FormMixin):
    model = Organization
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    template_name = 'org/org_view.html'
    form_class = ProductForm


    def test_func(self):
        org = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.profile == org.owned_by:
            return True
        return False

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        pk = self.object.serializable_value('pk')
        product = Product.objects.filter(org_id=pk)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

I need help to understand a few things:

1. how to execute the queries to retrieve all of his products and be able to see the category in which the product belongs.

My bad solution: the product variable holds all the products for that shop, including a cat_name_id that points to the category pk. Thats nice, but i need the name of the category.
i need something like this: print(product.category_name) and i should see 'Electronics'

2. how to execute a query that groups together items under the same category.

I already spent days trying to understand those queries, so please Explain like i`m five

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter all products of one user with the following command:

```
products = Product.objects.all().filter(org_id__owned_by=user)
```

See the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters. Here, 'user' is the user object from your User_Profile class.

With respect to your second question, I'm guessing that you want to order a specific query by category; in that case the statement would be:

```
products = Product.objects.order_by('cat_name')
```

Or you can combine the two with:

```
products = Product.objects.all().filter(org_id__owned_by=user).order_by('cat_name')
```